# How to subtract strings in python

Tags: python

Basically, if I have a string `'AJ'` and another string `'AJYF'`, I would like to be able to write `'AJYF'-'AJ'` and get `'YF'`.

I tried this but got a syntax error.

Just on a side note the subtractor will always will be shorter than the string it is subtracted from. Also, the subtractor will always be like the string it is subtracted from. For instance, if I have 'GTYF' and I want to subtract a string of length 3 from it, that string has to be 'GTY'.

If it is possible, the full function I am trying to do is convert a string to a list based on how long each item in the list is supposed to be. Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: Where is the code you tried, and how did it come up short?

Comment: It gave a sytax error

Comment: Also, that is the code I tried- 'AJYF'-'AJ' - and then I stored it as a variable

Comment: Add you code with the question if possible.

Comment: If it is possible, the full function I am trying to do is convert a string to a list based on how long each item in the list is suppose to be. Is their any way of doing that?

Comment: This sounds like something that `result = subtractee.replace(subtractor, '', 1)` might be the right answer.

Comment: What happens when ```AJYF - AB```?

Comment: In my code it never happens

Comment: Then just count and use slicing.

Comment: If you're just trying to remove the first N characters, you should just use `result = original[N:]` (string slicing).

Comment: @jaya Check the solutions

Comment: Not sure to understand your second question: "convert a string to a list based on how long each item in the list is suppose to be".
Give an example of input and an example of expected output.

Comment: maybe using `lstrip`, `rstrip`, and `split` functions in some way?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Easy Solution is:

```
>>> string1 = 'AJYF'
>>> string2 = 'AJ'
>>> if string2 in string1:
...     string1.replace(string2,'')
'YF'
>>>
```

Comment: That `if` check is not necessary. If `string2` is `not in string1`, the `replace` will do nothing and return the original string anyway...

Comment: This is not right: the OP clearly wants to "subtract" not from anywhere in the string but from the start, specifically. This would therefore fail if string1 == 'AJYF my poodle AJ Smith'.

Comment: Please check his side note for clarity, the solution is specific to the problem.

Answer (score 25):

I think what you want is this:

```
a = 'AJYF'
b = a.replace('AJ', '')
print b     # produces 'YF'
a = 'GTYF'
b = a.replace('GTY', '')
print b     # produces 'F'
```

Comment: This is not right: the OP clearly wants to "subtract" not from anywhere in the string but from the start, specifically. This would therefore fail if string1 == 'AJYF my poodle AJ Smith'. bli correctly deals with these considerations.

Answer (score 13):

`replace` can do something that you do not want if the second string is present at several positions:

```
s1 = 'AJYFAJYF'
s2 = 'AJ'
if s1.startswith(s2):
    s3 = s1.replace(s2, '')
s3
# 'YFYF'
```

You can add an extra argument to `replace` to indicate that you want only one replacement to happen:

```
if s1.startswith(s2):
    s3 = s1.replace(s2, '', 1)
s3
# 'YFAJYF'
```

Or you could use the `re` module:

```
import re
if s1.startswith(s2):
    s3 = re.sub('^' + s2, '', s1)
s3
# 'YFAJYF'
```

The `'^'` is to ensure that `s2` it is substituted only at the first position of `s1`.

Yet another approach, suggested in the comments, would be to take out the first `len(s2)` characters from `s1`:

```
if s1.startswith(s2):
    s3 = s1[len(s2):] 
s3
# 'YFAJYF'
```

Some tests using the %timeit magic in ipython (python 2.7.12, ipython 5.1.0) suggest that this last approach is faster:

```
In [1]: s1 = 'AJYFAJYF'

In [2]: s2 = 'AJ'

In [3]: %timeit s3 = s1[len(s2):]
The slowest run took 24.47 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 3: 87.7 ns per loop

In [4]: %timeit s3 = s1[len(s2):]
The slowest run took 32.58 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 3: 87.8 ns per loop

In [5]: %timeit s3 = s1[len(s2):]
The slowest run took 21.81 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 3: 87.4 ns per loop

In [6]: %timeit s3 = s1.replace(s2, '', 1)
The slowest run took 17.64 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 230 ns per loop

In [7]: %timeit s3 = s1.replace(s2, '', 1)
The slowest run took 17.79 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 228 ns per loop

In [8]: %timeit s3 = s1.replace(s2, '', 1)
The slowest run took 16.27 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 234 ns per loop

In [9]: import re

In [10]: %timeit s3 = re.sub('^' + s2, '', s1)
The slowest run took 82.02 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.85 µs per loop

In [11]: %timeit s3 = re.sub('^' + s2, '', s1)
The slowest run took 12.82 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.86 µs per loop

In [12]: %timeit s3 = re.sub('^' + s2, '', s1)
The slowest run took 13.08 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.84 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

if you insist on using the '-' operator, then use a class with the __ **sub** __ dunder method overitten, with a combination of one of the solutions provided above:

```
class String(object):
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.string = string

    def __sub__(self, other):
        if self.string.startswith(other.string):
            return self.string[len(other.string):]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.string


sub1 = String('AJYF') - String('AJ')
sub2 = String('GTYF') - String('GTY')
print(sub1)
print(sub2)
```

It prints:

```
YF
F
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for distinct characters in a string:

```
print(set(string1) ^ set(string2))
```