# Subtract from a list dict, the repeating sequence from another list

Tags: python, list, web-scraping

Considering this code:

```
def scrape_data(url, wanted_list):
    scraper = AutoScraper()
    scraper.build(url, wanted_list)
    result = scraper.get_result_similar(url, unique=False)
    return result

name_result = scrape_data(url, ["names"])

previous_name = []
with open("name.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") as name_file:
    reader = csv.reader(name_file)
    for row in reader:
        try:
            i = 0
            while True:
                previous_name.append(row[i])
                i += 1
        except(IndexError):
            pass


#Insert here the code to operate the subtraction

with open("new_name.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(result)
```

where *previous_name* is a list and a duplicate of *name_result*, which is a list | dict, **minus a variable number of elements at the beginning**, for example:

```
name_result = ["James", "Robert", "John", "Michael", "James", "Barbara", "Jessica"]
previous_name = [                   "John", "Michael", "James", "Barbara", "Jessica"]
```

I would like a subtraction that outputs, as the variable *result*, these first elements, the non duplicated "head" of *name_result*, i.e. in this example: `["James", "Robert"]`

This is not an elementwise subtraction: `"James"` is present in *previous_name* yet the desired output is not `["Robert"]`.

The problem is that what I have tried so far only amounted to elementwise subtraction (output `["Robert"]`):

- [How to subtract strings in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42798967/how-to-subtract-strings-in-python)

```py
set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(list2)
set1 - set2
```

- [How do I subtract one list from another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428536/how-do-i-subtract-one-list-from-another)

```py
[x for x in list1 if x not in list2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slice `name_result`

```
print(name_result[:len(name_result) - len(previous_name)]) # ['James', 'Robert']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code is working perfectly. I can finally finish my project!

Answer (score 0):

In cases where you have multiple occurrences of a list element, you might solve this by using a Counter:

```
from collections import Counter

def list_diff(name_result, previous_name):
    name_result_counter = Counter(name_result)
    previous_name_counter = Counter(previous_name)
    
    diff_counter = name_result_counter - previous_name_counter
    diff = list(diff_counter.elements())
    
    return diff

list_diff(name_result, previous_name) # returns ['James', 'Robert']
```

This will be more robust in cases where your list elements are not perfectly aligned (e.g. `previous_name` doesn't appear in exactly the same way in `name_result`).

Comment: I'm getting an error: `NameError: name 'difference_counter' is not defined`

Comment: Apologies—I fixed a typo and changed the references in the function. Try with the edited version.

Comment: The edited version of your code is now working, thanks a lot! Could you maybe explain me a little bit more why you say that "it will be more robust"? I'm not sure if I really understood what you said.

Comment: Welcome! By 'more robust' I meant that it checks for all occurrences of 'James' in the list—whether 'James' occurs as the first element in `name_result` or nested in the middle somewhere, it will still return `['James', 'Robert']`. 

In a smaller example, if you have `name_result = ["Robert", "John", "James"]` and `previous_name = [                   "John"]` the solution will still return `['James', 'Robert']`, but a solution that subtracts their lengths will return `['John', 'James']` which is not what you want.